# Get-WindowsFeature and Select-Object not displaying installed state?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to create a script that would highlight missing features by comparing features I need installed with the installed features on a server, that I placed in my array variable in powershell.
But I cannot figure out why the installed state is not displaying on my powershell?

This is the script:

```
$InstallState = "Install State"

Get-WindowsFeature | Select-Object "Name",$InstallState | Where-Object {$_.$InstallState -like "Available"}
```

I have also tried this

```
$InstallState = "Install State"

Get-WindowsFeature | Select-Object "Name",$InstallState
```

I get the Name, but the Install State is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no space. You can see the members with the `Get-Member` command

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Get-Member

InstallState              Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.InstallState InstallState {get;}
```

Simply change it to

```
$InstallState = "InstallState"

Get-WindowsFeature | Select-Object "Name",$InstallState | Where-Object {$_.$InstallState -like "Available"}
```

Comment: wow.... can't believe I got tricked by the interface. Thanks a lot, also learned about the Get-Member, very useful.